# Make use of web component library in Kotlin Compose for Web

Tags: kotlin, web-component, kotlin-js, jetbrains-compose, compose-for-web

I want to tinker with Kotlin Compose for Web a bit.
In some of my past web projects, I made use of some web components of the [Clarity Design System (CDS)](https://clarity.design/).

In a JavaScript or TypeScript project,
you first need to install both npm packages`@cds/core` and `@cds/city`.
Secondly, you have to include some global stylesheets, e.g. via HTML or sass-import.
For each component you want to use, you need to import the corresponding `register.js`.
Lastly, you can include the component in your HTML like any other tag:

```html
<cds-button>Click me!</cds-button>
```

I tried to replicate the steps with Kotlin Compose for Web, but wasn't able to get it to work.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've got it to work now, which included several steps.

1. *Install npm dependencies*

```kotlin
kotlin {
    ...
    
    sourceSets {
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // dependencies for Compose for Web
                implementation(compose.web.core)
                implementation(compose.runtime)

                // dependencies for Clarity Design System
                implementation(npm("@cds/core", "5.6.0"))
                implementation(npm("@cds/city", "1.1.0"))

                // dependency for webpack - see step 3
                implementation(npm("file-loader", "6.2.0"))
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

2. *Enable css support*
   This seems to be required, in order to include the global stylesheets.

```kotlin
kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            ... 
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

3. *Add support for `.woff2` files included in stylesheet of Clarity*
   The stylesheet of CDS include font files of type `.woff2`, whose support in webpack must be configured.
   This can be achieved by creating the file `webpack.config.d/support-fonts.js`
   at the project root with the following content:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|gif|png|jpe?g)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/'
        }
    }]
});
```

4. *Include global stylesheets*

```kotlin
external fun require(module: String): dynamic

fun main() {
    require("modern-normalize/modern-normalize.css")
    require("@cds/core/global.min.css")
    require("@cds/core/styles/module.shims.min.css")
    require("@cds/city/css/bundles/default.min.css")
    
    ...
}
```

5. *Import `register.js` for desired web component*

```kotlin
external fun require(module: String): dynamic

fun main() {
    ...
    
    require("@cds/core/button/register.js")

    ...
}
```

5. *Create @Composable for the web component*
   Sadly this solution makes use of APIs marked as `@OptIn(ComposeWebInternalApi::class)`,
   which stands for "This API is internal and is likely to change in the future".
   Any hints on how this may be implemented without relying on internal APIs are appreciated.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CdsButton(
    status: CdsButtonStatus = CdsButtonStatus.Primary,
    attrs: AttrBuilderContext<HTMLElement>? = null,
    content: ContentBuilder<HTMLElement>? = null
) = TagElement(
    elementBuilder = CdsElementBuilder("cds-button"),
    applyAttrs = {
        if (attrs != null) apply(attrs)

        attr("status", status.attributeValue)
    },
    content = content
)

/**
 * This is a copy of the private class org.jetbrains.compose.web.dom.ElementBuilderImplementation
 */
internal class CdsElementBuilder<TElement : Element>(private val tagName: String) : ElementBuilder<TElement> {
    private val element: Element by lazy {
        document.createElement(tagName)
    }

    override fun create(): TElement = element.cloneNode() as TElement
}

sealed interface CdsButtonStatus {
    object Primary : CdsButtonStatus
    ...
}

internal val CdsButtonStatus.attributeValue
    get() = when (this) {
        CdsButtonStatus.Primary -> "primary"
        ...
    }
```

6. Make us of your `@Composable`!

```kotlin
fun main() {
    ...
    
    renderComposable(rootElementId = "root") {
        CdsButton(
            status = CdsButtonStatus.Success
        ) {
            Text("It works! :-)")
        }
    }
}
```